# Contour results are not accurate with detection binary mask edges

Tags: opencv

Now I have this mask generated based on the size of an image and I have a set of rectangles to know where are these rectangles so I tried to extract contours to know where are these rectangles ...

[image: mask generated]

```
 mask = np.zeros((image.shape[0], image.shape[1]), dtype=np.uint8)  # Mask of original image
 #some process to draw these rectangles merged...
 _, bw = cv2.threshold(mask, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
 img, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(bw.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
 for j in range(len(contours)):
        outputBoxes.append(cv2.boundingRect(contours[j]))
```

Another trial

```
_, bws = cv2.threshold(mask, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
img, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(bws, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, offset=(0,0))
cv2.drawContours(bws, contours,-1,(255,255,0))
img, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(bws, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, offset=(0,0))
```

but with no vain

I can't get the rect dimensions exactly or even approximately
** NOTE This generated image is small part of long process

[image: second example]
first one I detected some rects so I merged them as one in the second one then I should take this white one dimensions to be determined in the original one
As seen, it is not accurate too
`Python` or `c++` are good for me
`opencv 3.x`

Comment: what are you getting and what do you expect?

Comment: Have you tried outputting/displaying the results? If so, please share them here.

Comment: I got wrong dimensions, not the expected

Comment: I added another example

Answer (score 1):

Here is the results I get:

[image]

Obviously from here you have pretty clear contours and you can just print out the lengths.

With this code:

```
Mat origImage = mat;
    Mat canny_output = mat;
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    cv::Mat greyMat, colorMat;
    cv::cvtColor(mat, greyMat, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    int thresh = 100;
    RNG rng(12345);
    ///// Detect edges using canny
    Canny(greyMat, canny_output, thresh, thresh * 2, 3);
    /// Find contours
    findContours(canny_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));
    int largest_area = 0;
    int largest_contour_index = 0;
    Rect bounding_rect;
    /// Draw contours
    Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(canny_output.size(), CV_8UC3);
    for (int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++)
    {
        Scalar color = Scalar(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255));
        drawContours(drawing, contours, i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point());
        double a=contourArea( contours[i],false);  //  Find the area of contour
       if(a>largest_area){
       largest_area=a;
       largest_contour_index=i;                //Store the index of largest contour
       bounding_rect=boundingRect(contours[i]); // Find the bounding rectangle for biggest contour
       }
    }
    rectangle(origImage, bounding_rect, Scalar(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255)),2);
    /// Show in a window
    namedWindow("Contours", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    resize(drawing, drawing, Size(640, 480));
    resize(mat, mat, Size(640, 480));
    resize(origImage, origImage, Size(640, 480));
    imshow("Contours", drawing);

    cv::namedWindow("img");
    cv::imshow("mat", mat);
    cv::imshow("mat", origImage);
    cv::imshow("mat123", drawing);
    cv::waitKey(0);
```